# Generating response from an async queue in Camel

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Is it possible to have a synchronous camel activemq queue (e.g. MY_QUEUE) with the following properties:

1. MY_QUEUE sends its input to EXT_QUEUE.REQ (straightforward)
2. Generate the response for MY_QUEUE from EXT_QUEUE.RES (not sure how to!)

and the populate the response body for MY_QUEUE from EXT_QUEUE.RES, where MY_QUEUE, EXT_QUEUE.REQ and EXT_QUEUE.RES are all activemq queues.

E.g. MY_QUEUE ---> EXT_QUEUE.REQ

If so, how may I go about configuring it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a route somewhere along the line of this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:MY_QUEUE?exchangePattern=InOut"/>
    <bean ref="myConverter" method="prepExternalCall"/>
    <enrich uri="activemq:queue:EXT_QUEUE.REQ?replyTo=EXT_QUEUE.REQ.RES&amp;replyToType=Shared"/>
    <bean ref="myConverter" method="postProcessResponse"/>
</route>
```

After the method `postProcessResponse(Exchange ex)` returns, the exchange is sent back to MY_QUEUE (enforced by the query parameter `exchangePattern=InOut`) if a JMS reploy-to destination has been set by the sender. The processing is synchronous in the sense that the next message is only picked up from MY_QUEUE after the response to the current message has been sent.